# C++ Wrapper of .lib implemented in Pascal

Tags: c++, dll

I've a C++ Builder project that uses this library http://www.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=1881 (Cipher).

- Source files are included (.hpp / .pas)
- .lib file is included

Seems to be that it is a C++ Builder library but I want to write a wrapper in C++ in order to use it in C++ programs and C# programs (simply said, make a DLL of this lib).

My problem is that i'm a totally beginner and don't know how to do such thing.

Should I include the lib file in my project and declare all functions in `extern` in order to wrap it?

I need some help, thanks.

Comment: Read the C++ Builder help topics on creating DLLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to match up API calls and that gets redundant and boring. However, it seems to me, that the work is justified because your DLL can be used pretty much from anywhere at this point. The goal would be to wrap the C++ Builder project because it is compiling the .pas files which compiler friendly outside of a C++ Builder/Delphi world.

It has been my experience that writing "C" functions that accept an opaque pointer is the most flexible approach here:

```
typedef void * MYHANDLE;

extern "C" MYHANDLE CreateMyObject(void)
{
    MyCppObject * obj = new MyCppObject();
    return static_cast<MYHANDLE>(obj);
}

/* Calls to your other C++ methods as well */

extern "C" void DeleteMyObject(MYHANDLE obj)
{
    MyCppObject * ptr = static_cast<MyCppObject*>(obj);
    delete ptr;
}
```